# functions in a php router

Tags: php, function, routes

I have been trying to create a router for my php app,I am kinda new to mvc. I did some research and landed on a tutorial at [requiremind.com](http://requiremind.com/a-most-simple-php-mvc-beginners-tutorial/) that helped me do this. How ever there is this line of code that has been making me pull out my hair.
this is my code for the router.

```
<?php
function call($controller, $action) {

// require the file that matches the controller name
require_once('controllers/' . $controller . '_controller.php');

// create a new instance of the needed controller
switch($controller) {
  case 'pages':
    $controller = new PagesController();
  break;
}

// call the action
$controller->{ $action }();
}

 // just a list of the controllers we have and their actions
 // we consider those "allowed" values
 $controllers = array('pages' => ['home', 'error']);

 // check that the requested controller and action are both allowed
 // if someone tries to access something else he will be redirected to the error action of the pages controller
 if (array_key_exists($controller, $controllers)) {
  if (in_array($action, $controllers[$controller])) {
      call($controller, $action);
  } else {
     call('pages', 'error');
  }
  } else {
     call('pages', 'error');
  }
   ?>
```

this is the part giving me headache `$controller->{ $action }();`.
The comment says it calls the action . But i do not have a function like action() anywhere.
I know there are different ways of creating a router but I would really want to understand how this particular one works.
I need someone to kindly help me understand what this part of the code does.

Comment: That line calls a method named as specified in the _value_ contained in the variable `$action`, so for example `edit` or `delete`. It is sometimes referred to as variable method call.

Comment: @arkascha wow. Makes sense now. Thanks alot. I didn't realize that. Thanks alot

Comment: You could try creating the class with `$class=ucfirst($controller)."Controller"; $controller= new $class();` saves all of the case statements.

Answer (score 0):

Use method_exists func

```
if(method_exists($controller, $action)) {
  $controller->$action();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this particular m-v-c application , looks like the author wanted the function `call()` to be the main function of the application , you analyze the request then call the function `call` with the appropriate controller and action. here is usage example of this code,

```
<?php
$path = trim(parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH), "/");
$pathParts = explode("/", $path);

switch ($pathParts[0]){
    //www.example.com/home
    case "home":
        call("homePageController",'showPagefunction');
        break;
    //www.example.com/contact
    case "contact":
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET"){
            call("contactPageController",'showPageFunction');
        }else if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
            call("contactPageController",'postContactMsgFunction');
        }
        break;
    default:
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
        die("404 error");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

That line calls a method named as specified in the *value* contained in the variable `$action`, so for example `edit` or `delete`. It is sometimes referred to as variable method call.

*This answer was submitted by @arkaschar in the comments section*